# Translated category names

Tags: multistore, category, localisation

I would like to have a single category tree in my Magento store, used by different store views: English, French and German.

Is it possible to have the category data translated instead of creating different category trees for each store?

If so how do you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change the Storeview in the upper left and then change the name for this storeview:
[image: Category name per store view]